# Using Django, switched from heroku + gunicorn to digitalocean + nginx + gunicorn, site now broken

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, http-status-code-302

I had my django app on heroku for a while with no problems. I now want to move it to a digital ocean droplet, partly as a learning exercise, partly for scalability (and cost) reasons.

After following [this](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) excellent tutorial almost to the letter, the app is working but with a huge gotcha: I now get an infinite redirect loop when I try to log in to the admin site. The first request is a POST ?next=/admin/ with the username and password, this gets a 302 response to redirect to GET /admin/, which gets a 302 response redirect to ?next=/admin/, and so on.

I have spent 2 or 3 hours with google and various nginx tutorials and this is the first time my "google the error message, copy and paste random code snippets, repeat" algorithm has ever failed me, I'm hoping the reason is that the error is trivial to solve and I just can't see it?

If it's not trivial to solve, let me know and I'll post more info.

Thanks in advance

edit 1: my nginx config file for the app is basically a verbatim copy of the tutorial. It looks like this:

```
upstream hello_app_server {
 # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
 # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
 # single worker for timing out).

 server unix:/webapps/hello_django/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

   listen   80;
   server_name example.com;

   client_max_body_size 4G;

   access_log /webapps/hello_django/logs/nginx-access.log;
   error_log /webapps/hello_django/logs/nginx-error.log;
   location /static/ {
       alias   /webapps/hello_django/static/;
   }

   location /media/ {
       alias   /webapps/hello_django/media/;
   }

   location / {
       # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
       #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

       # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
       # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
       # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

       # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
       # can be set properly within the Rack application
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

       # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
       # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
       proxy_redirect off;

       # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
       # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
       # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
       # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
       # clients, really.
       # proxy_buffering off;

       # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
       # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
       if (!-f $request_filename) {
           proxy_pass http://hello_app_server;
           break;
       }
   }

   # Error pages
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
   location = /500.html {
       root /webapps/hello_django/static/;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest, see my edit for nginx config code, let me know if there's other code you need to see.